# How make a stackpanel allign right?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7

In my application, i'm using a list, which has four datas 1)name 2)date 3)image 4)petname
end the xaml code i've used for that is,

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="450" Height="90" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0" Height="90" Width="225">
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="60" Margin="0,15" FontWeight="Medium" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Name}" Width="225" FontSize="25"/>
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="39" Margin="4,51,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Date}" Width="221" Foreground="Gray" FontSize="16"/>
                </Grid>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0" Width="225" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                    <Image Name="ImgBox" Height="46" Source="/attach-30x30.png" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="40" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding petname}" FontSize="24" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Portable User Interface"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
```

What i want is, i want the image being immediately followed by petname and both of them should be right alligned.
What i want is,
[image: this one]

But what i get is,
[image: this one]

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set FlowDirection=RighToLeft for the inner stackpanel, then swap the order of the image and textblock

Comment: Setting stackpanel's flowdirection=rightToLeft will make it align right. But also make it stacks its content from right to left, so you need to reorder the content in xaml

Comment: that works fine, but some of text in the text block is not visible?

Comment: you mean like cropped at the right side? I'm not sure why, maybe the textblock spanning out of screen to the right..

Answer (score 0):

Your Grid should span across all controls. Try this sample:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="450" Height="90" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0" Height="90" Width="450">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="60" Margin="0,15" FontWeight="Medium" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Name}" Width="225" FontSize="25"/>
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="39" Margin="4,51,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Date}" Width="221" Foreground="Gray" FontSize="16"/>

                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                        <Image Name="ImgBox" Height="46"  Source="/attach-30x30.png" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="40"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding petname}" FontSize="24" TextAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Portable User Interface"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
```